# Handling Checkbox via puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I want to click the verify human checkbox of Cloudflare's just a moment page. How can I do it?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = process.argv[2];
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
  await navigationPromise;
  const checkboxel = await page.waitForSelector("#select-all-checkbox");
  checkboxel.click();
  const pageContent = await page.content();
  fs.writeFileSync('wpresponse.txt', pageContent);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Can you share the target url?

Comment: http://deesec.me/

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the checkbox is not enough to pass the Cludflare protection.

BTW since the question is about how to click the checkbox, here's the answer:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('iframe')

const elementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.click('input[type="checkbox"]');

// await page.screenshot({path: './image.jpg'})
```

If you uncomment the screenshot line, you'll see that the checkbox is clicked and that the spinner is loading. The browser won't pass the control and the page will reload.

I t's required an advanced browser customization, starting from a real userAgent (which is not enough tho)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the click action:

```js
await checkboxel.click();
```

Also your checkbox is not present in the page, you can run with the browser screen by using

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false })
```

And then you can inspect your page:
[image]

We can see here that the checkbox `#select-all-checkbox` is not present.

The only checkbox present is inside an `iframe` which I don't think you can access with browser automation.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Using selenium can I access the checkbox present inside an iframe?

Comment: I don't think you can. I believe the only way would be to create a browser extension.

Comment: Also, can we first find the exact location (coordinates) of a checkbox element and then use Puppeteer to click it?

Comment: You can't access the checkbox, so you can't get it's position. Even if you use hardcoded position (which would not work on different screen or resolution), I don't think the click event would be sent to the iframe.